# Distribute Java application in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I wish to distribute my restaurant application, which uses MySQL to store the data. I plan to use Lauch4j to distribute its .exe file.

But the program also requires the user to have mysql Installed, is it possible to hard code mysql setup within the application? or anything else that could be done to avoid the user the pain of downloading and installing it?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use MySQL? If not you might try to use an embedded database management system like derby. That would not require any installation.

Comment: The data is shared across 2 lan computers, the Main Order computer and the one in the Kitchen

Comment: In that case you'd need to install the DBMS only on one computer and thus installing it with the application might not be useful. Additionally, you should try to minimize communication over the database, you better route the client's request through the server app which could then contain an embedded database. If that's still not an option I'd go with SJuan76's answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of opinion, but I advise you to not do it.

If your main concern is the install process being easy for the user, use some embedded DB. That way, the user not only will not have to care about things like firewalls, possible mysql vulnerabilities and so on.

If you need something that only mysql or other standalone DBs can provide you, don't hide it from the user. Technical capable users should be allowed to configure your app to run in the sql engines they already have installed (if they want to). Other people should at least know that you are installing something else apart of your app. Of course less tech-savy users will be scared, but if they do not know what they are doing they should not be tinkering with MySQL (or even installing programs).

In essence: Let the people know what you are installing in their systems. Allow them to reuse other DB engines if they chose to.

If i was you, if MySQL was the option, I would just take it for granted that it is installed and ask for the connection parameters (make it the first step of the installation procedure so you can check it before proceeding).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) in for your application. `If any application needs to store data in the same system only and the application needs to be small and lightweight application then you can use sqlite as database.` SQLite makes a great application file format.